# How Can I Enable particular List Column to Another User But It is not to visible for current user

Tags: list, ootb

My Requirement is when we have 2 users one user is list have 5 columns 
and for that List another User want to edit that particular list then one more Additional Column should be visible to that user

Example: i have created one list and i can perform changes in that list
but another user can edit that list he has to mention reason why he is editing in particular one column i.e comments box.

is this possible in sharepoint ??

please make a comment

Comment: How are you differentiating user 1 and user 2. Is it by role? or any other parameter? There is an opportunity to hide using javascript based on condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new list and have the lookup be the original list. So instead of a list column in the same list, create a NEW list -- with edited permissions -- and have one of the columns be a lookup column to the original list.

In short, there is no way to have a column hidden from one individual--the permissions are per list or per list item, but not column.

Comment: suppose User 1 have 5 columns , for User 2 should have those 5 columns with an additional Column i.e Comments                                                                     for user 2 should able to get that particular Comment Column ( Single Line Text / Multi line Text)

Comment: user1 and user2 will see 5 columns. it is by design, there is no way to hide columns from individuals--like I said, only lists or list items, among other objects.